Change MessageTop of the button excel export on DataTable after redraw
Just want to ask if you have any idea how to change the messageTop on button excel.
buttons: [
    'pageLength',
    {
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        footer: true,
        filename: 'PurchaseReport_' + new Date().getTime(),
        title: 'Purchase Report',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: ':visible'
        },
        messageTop: "User: " + userTypeValue + "\nCompany: " + accountNoValue + "\nDate From: " + dateFromValue + "\nDate To: " + dateToValue,
        customize: function (xlsx) {
            var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];

            $('c[r=A2] t', sheet).text("User: " + userTypeValue + "\nCompany: " + accountNoValue + "\nDate From: " + dateFromValue + "\nDate To: " + dateToValue);
        }
    }
],

This will not work because there is no value yet for userTypeValue and accountNoValue during datatable initialization.
I want to change the messageTop value when the code below is triggered during search.
dataTable.clear(); // Clear existing data in DataTable
dataTable.draw(); // Redraw the DataTable`

I initialize the datatable initially with empty data.
data: \[\], //empty array initially

Then I just call the draw() method whenever I have data to add on the table.
dataTable.clear(); // Clear existing data in DataTable
dataTable.rows.add(data); // Add new data to DataTable  dataTable.draw(); // Redraw the DataTable

I have already tried adding action on buttons but I don't want to redo the downloading part of the excel. It seems not working for me as well. Customize seems to be working only on initialization.
And drawCallBack looks like I got an issue with the clear() method.

There are a lot of details missing from the question (see [mre]). But maybe you can approach this in a different way... Try using a function for messageTop - something like this: messageTop: function () { ... }. Now you can write JavaScript logic for the ... function details - an if/else which checks if the variables are undefined. Then you can return a different message string as appropriate.

See this official example which basically does that with a variable. Functions are executed for every export, instead of what you have (a never-changing hard-coded string).
